# Holder inequality application

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm assuming you use the Holder inequality for this.

If $s < t$ and $\mu(X) = 1$ (i.e $\mu$ is a probability measure) is it true that

$$\left(\int_{X} |f|^{s} d\mu\right)^{\dfrac{1}{s}} \leq \left(\int_{X} |f|^{t} d\mu\right)^{\dfrac{1}{t}}?$$

My idea was to start by noting that $\cfrac{1}{1+\frac{t}{s}} + \cfrac{1}{1+\frac{s}{t}} = 1$

But I couldn't really get anywhere by doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Holder inequality with $t/s$ and its conjugate $\frac{t}{t-s}$. Then, you get:
$$\int_X |f|^s \leq \Bigg( \int_X |f|^t \Bigg)^{s/t} \mu(X)^{\frac{t-s}{t}}$$
whenever $\mu(X) < \infty$.
Raising to $1/s$, you get:
$$\Bigg( \int_X |f|^s \Bigg)^{1/s} \leq \Bigg(\int_X |f|^t \Bigg)^{1/t} \mu(X)^{\frac{t-s}{ts}}$$
Yours is a special case with $\mu(X) = 1$.